# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in selenium-webdriver

Tags: angular6

I found this error :

ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/mac/angular/restaurantApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http'

Can any one help me to solve that.

Thanks

Comment: okay really sorry, coz this was my mistake. accidentally i imported httpClient instead of httpClientModule.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have had a similar problem with error code:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/my.service.ts   
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/http' in '...\src\app
```

Problem was with Visual Studio Code's Autoimport plugin importing HttpClient class from

```
'../../node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/http'
```

instead of

```
'../../node_modules/@angular/common/http'
```

I found this question somehow helpful, but it did not give me a clear answer. I post what I found out so that another visitor will have it easier.

Comment: I have the similar issue why is it importing from '/selenium-webdriver/http' ?

Comment: You can find where this is happening by doing a project wide search for `from 'selenium-webdriver/http';`

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue when I was working with Angular and Laravel
where I wanted to add HTTP module in `app.module.ts` and also in  `my.component.ts` 
but it added to the selenium HTTP client.

So I changed from

```
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
```

To

```
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 1):

For other visitors. I added `import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';` instead of `import { HttpClient } from '../../../node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/http';`
 in custom servsiv

Answer (score 1):

My problem had been resolved by replacing

```
=>    import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
to => import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

from my one ts file in angular 7

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I imported the `HttpClient` from `selenium-webdriver/http`:

```
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
```

Replace this line with:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved change auto import do httpclient at import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

Answer (score 0):

**it means to change** 
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http'; 
**to** 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';